# MySQL Trigger student rank

Tags: mysql, triggers

> how can i convert this to a trigger (student Rank)

```
SET @prev_value = NULL;
SET @rank_count = 0;
SET @rank_increasing = 0;
SELECT @rank_increasing := @rank_increasing + 1 AS NO
     , CASE
       WHEN @prev_value = a.total_score
          THEN @rank_count
       WHEN @prev_value := a.total_score
          THEN @rank_count := @rank_increasing 
        END AS RANK
     , a.*
  FROM ( SELECT STUDENT_ID,TERM,YEAR,
 SUM(TEST)  AS total_score

           FROM studentmark
          GROUP BY STUDENT_ID
          ORDER BY total_score DESC
       ) a
```

> Can anyone help me to make  this

Comment: trigger on what action?

Comment: multiple actions insert,update

Comment: Why store this at all

Comment: i need to make separate table